# Automatically insert a python data frame in quip

Tags: python, dataframe, automation, insert, quip

I have a data frame:

[image: data drama df]

I want to automatically insert the data frame details in quip. I have searched online, but couldn't find any satisfactory answer. Please help

Comment: Pretty sure there was a method `update_spreadsheet_row` in [quip.py](https://github.com/quip/quip-api/blob/master/python/quip.py).

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer based on a similar problem and this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/updating-a-quip-spreadsheet-with-python-api-1b4bb24d4aac

First, follow the step to get and use a personal access token from quip.com/dev/token--this will help with your authentication.

Then, you can get an updated client version from Lynn Zheng's medium post (linked above) https://github.com/RuolinZheng08/quip-api for local import.

My imports look like this:

```
import quip_update as quip #from Zheng's repo
from login_token import login_token #this is a variable that holds the value of the token I got from their auth website
```

Then you setup/authorize the client with the following:

```
quip_client = quip.QuipClient(access_token=login_token, base_url='https://platform.quip.com')
```

user = quip_client.get_authenticated_user()

If your company has a contract with quip, it might look like `base_url='https://platform.quip-amazon.com'`

I like to `print(user)` to see basic info/that the client connected.

Then, again mostly narrating Zheng's article, you can use one of the client functions to insert a spreadsheet:

```
def add_to_spreadsheet(self, thread_id, *rows, **kwargs):
'''Adds the given rows to the named (or first) spreadsheet in the
        given document.

            client = quip.QuipClient(...)
            client.add_to_spreadsheet(thread_id, ["5/1/2014", 2.24])'''
```

from [quip.py](https://github.com/quip/quip-api/tree/master/python)

So you can put a spreadsheet in manually and then call to it by name="name of spreadsheet" to incorporate rows from Pandas.

So, for example: [image: sample commands to update spreadsheet in document]